# GridView Update button execute update SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

[image]

SQL Server stored procedure accepts the parameters, current company name, new company name and whether it already exists which has a default value. When the edit button is clicked on the front end UI, the grid view allows me to edit the company name. This shows an 'Update' button - when this is clicked - the code parses however nothing updates and company name does not update either.

Breakpoint is set and stepped through and `@CurrentCompanyName` is returned as null. Not sure how to fix this.

Aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="CompanyTable" runat="server" 
     OnRowEditing="CompanyTable_RowEditing" 
     OnRowCancelingEdit="CompanyTable_RowCancelingEdit" 
     OnRowUpdating="CompanyTable_RowUpdating" 
     OnPageIndexChanging="CompanyTable_PageIndexChanging" 
     PageSize="20" Font-Underline="False" AllowPaging="True">
    <HeaderStyle Width="150px" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
            <ControlStyle CssClass="ButtonDesigntwo" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Edit" ButtonType="Button" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" ButtonType="Button" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Button ID="Update" ButtonType="Button" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>  
                <asp:Button ID="Cancel" ButtonType="Button" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"/>  
            </EditItemTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="tableHeaderStyle" />
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" BorderColor="Black" ForeColor="White" Font-Underline="False" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="tableRowStyle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Method code:

```
 protected void CompanyTable_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[updateCompanyName]", cn))
        {
            TextBox name = CompanyTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CompanyTable") as TextBox;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentCompanyName", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewCompanyName", CompanyInputTextBox.Text).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            SqlParameter objisExists = new SqlParameter("@isExists", SqlDbType.Int);
            objisExists.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(objisExists);

            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();

            int isExists = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@isExists"].Value.ToString());

            if (isExists == 0)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "111", "AddCompanyUpdating();", true);
            }
            else if (isExists == 1)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "111", "CompanyNotUpdatedValidation();", true);
            }
        }

        // Setting the EditIndex property to -1 to cancel the Edit mode in Gridview  
        CompanyTable.EditIndex = -1;

        // Call ShowData method for displaying updated data  
        BindData();
    }
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateCompanyName] 
    @CurrentCompanyName VARCHAR(50),
    @NewCompanyName VARCHAR(50),
    @IsExists INT = 0 OUT 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CompanyID INT

    SELECT @CompanyID = CompanyID 
    FROM company 
    WHERE companyname = @CurrentCompanyName

    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT CompanyName 
                   FROM company 
                   WHERE companyname = @NewCompanyName )
        BEGIN
            SET @IsExists = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN   
            UPDATE COMPANY
            SET CompanyName = @NewCompanyName 
            WHERE companyid = @CompanyID

            SET @IsExists = 0
        END
    END

    PRINT @isexists 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `name` as a textbox in this line:

```
TextBox name = CompanyTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CompanyTable") as TextBox;
```

Then you try to set the value of your parameter to the textbox in this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentCompanyName", name);
```

When what you SHOULD be doing, is setting the parameter value to the TEXT that is IN the textbox:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentCompanyName", name.Text);
```

EDIT:

Since `name` itself is NULL when you are hovering over it, that means that you have not correctly defined it in this line:

```
TextBox name = CompanyTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CompanyTable") as TextBox;
```

Stop the code in the debugger and open a quick view into CompanyTable, and see if you can figure out the correct way to define the textbox you are looking for.

EDIT 2:   In defining your TextBox, you are doing `FindControl("CompanyTable")`, but according to your markup, "CompanyTable" is the ID of your GridView, not a textbox.   In fact, I don't see any markup anywhere for a textbox in the first code sample you posted.

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Line 148:                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentCompanyName", name.Text);

Comment: Tried what you suggested and got the above unhandled exception

Comment: Tab has explained what you need to do to solve this. It is a bug in your code that requires you to set a break point and figure out what is not being set correctly. We can't do this remotely.